# ImageIO.read() works in Eclipse runtime but not as runnable jar file

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I've got a problem with loading images implemented in a jar file. Here's my file tree:

```
    -graphics
    -ImageFiles
         -animation
              -image.jpg
    -mathspace
    -META-INF
```

Now I wanna load this image:

```
    ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/ImageFiles/animation/image.jpg"));
```

This works well in the eclipse runtime but when I start it as a runnable jar File a NullPointerException gets triggered. Thanks for help!

Comment: please post the relevant part of code and the stack trace

Comment: public void init(){

Comment: Can you paste some more :)

Comment: sorry XD Didn't want to write a comment

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What does your step debugger tell you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score -1):

```
public void init() {
 try {
  img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getRessource("/ImageFiles/animation/image.jpg"));
 } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 repaint();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
 if (img != null) {
  g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
 }

}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!